# Cannot Install openjdk-7-jdk with dockerfile from Ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, docker

As in title, I can not install openjdk-7-jdk using dockerfile from Ubuntu 14.04.
At that command `RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk` I get the following error

> Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
>   --fix-missing?
>
> failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y
>   openjdk-7-jdk' returned a non-zero code: 100

Before I already use `RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y` and additionally I was trying `RUN sudo apt-get -f install`. I read that people find a way to do this using Packages in the PPA, but it's not recommended because of the lack of security.